# get the path in a file inside {} by python

Tags: python

I have a code and I just want to have /X/Y/Z/C, /X/Y/Z/D, /X/Y/Z/E back(whatever comes after -tree).
It should actually reads the file, ignores everything till it sees WFS and then get the information in {}, find tree and just gives me the paths back.

I am a beginner in Python. The match pattern doesn't work cause I think the path changes every day. 
any help will be appreciated.

The code:

```
DEFAULTS
{
    FS
    {
        -A      AAA
        -B

    }  -aaaaaa
    C
    {

    } 
}

D "FW0" 
{
} 

WFS "C:" XXXX:"/C"
{
    -trees
        "/X/Y/Z/C"
        "/X/Y/Z/D"
        "/X/Y/Z/E"
    -A  AAA
}
```

Comment: What's the expected output for this input?

Comment: The output should give back the paths after "-trees".

Comment: So in your case the three lines in quotes?

Comment: yes but it always vary. one day maybe it is 1 line, the next day 8 lines.

Comment: May I ask what is this special format? Can you find a parser (e.g. JSON) for your need?

Comment: Would "lines" between `-trees` and `-A` be reliable enough logic - or is that likely to change?

Comment: If you mean the format of what comes after -tress, the format of the paths will be always like this: " /../.." but everyday they could be more or less. (Hope to understood you right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A state machine-based lexical analyzer would do the trick reliably.

It recognizes the file's constructs that interest us: nested curly braces, named sections (an identifier and an opening brace on the following line; this one only cares about top-level sections) and clauses (started by `-identifier` inside a top-level section, possibly followed by data lines and terminated by another clause or the section's end).

Then it keeps reading the file and prints data lines found if they happen to be in the section and clause we're interested in. It also sets a flag upon finding them in order to quit immediately after that clause ends.

```
f = open("t.txt")

import re

identifier=None
brace_level=0
section=None
clause=None
req_clause_found=False
def in_req_clause(): return section=='WFS' and clause=='trees'

for l in (l.strip() for l in f):
    if req_clause_found and not in_req_clause(): break

    m=re.match(r'[A-Z]+',l)    #adjust if section names can be different
    if m and section is None:
        identifier=m.group(0)
        continue
    m=re.match(r'\{(\s|$)',l)
    if m:
        brace_level+=1
        if identifier is not None and brace_level==1:
            section=identifier
            identifier=None
        continue
    else: identifier=None
    m=re.match(r'\}(\s|$)',l)
    if m:
        brace_level-=1
        if brace_level==0: section=None
        clause=None
        continue
    m=re.match(r'-([A-Za-z]+)',l)   #adjust if clause names can be different
    if m and brace_level==1:
        clause=m.group(1)
        continue
    m=re.match(r'"(.*)"$',l)
    if m and in_req_clause():
        print m.group(1)
        req_clause_found=True
        continue
```

On the sample, this outputs

```
/X/Y/Z/C
/X/Y/Z/D
/X/Y/Z/E
```

Comment: really Thanks. It works on the code which I presented here. How and where I can learn more about the approach you used? I mean using identifier, clauses,...

Comment: Any comprehensible overview info for state machines and lexical analysis for their basic principles. The state here is all the variables combined. Instead of checking the state first and then the input (the canonical approach for state machines), I check input first and then the state (implicitly ignoring the input if the state is not relevant) - this produces less code for this kind of task. "Identifiers", "sections" and "clauses" are just names I invented to designate the file's constructs I recognize here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by the layout of your file but is there any reason not to parse it line-by-line?

```
def parse():
    with open('data.txt') as fptr:
        for line in fptr:
            if line.startswith('WFS'):
                for line in fptr:
                    if line.strip().startswith('-trees'):
                        result = []
                        for line in fptr:
                            if line.strip().startswith('"'):
                                result.append(line.strip())
                            else:
                                return result
```

That's not pretty but I think it'll work! Let's try it:

```
In [1]: !cat temp.txt
DEFAULTS
{
    FS
    {
        -A      AAA
        -B

    }  -aaaaaa
    C
    {

    } 
}

D "FW0" 
{
} 

WFS "C:" XXXX:"/C"
{
    -trees
        "/X/Y/Z/C"
        "/X/Y/Z/D"
        "/X/Y/Z/E"
    -A  AAA
}

In [2]: %cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:def parse():
:    with open('temp.txt') as fptr:
:        for line in fptr:
:            if line.startswith('WFS'):
:                for line in fptr:
:                    if line.strip().startswith('-trees'):
:                        result = []
:                        for line in fptr:
:                            if line.strip().startswith('"'):
:                                result.append(line.strip())
:                            else:
:                                return result
:
:--

In [3]: parse()
Out[3]: ['"/X/Y/Z/C"', '"/X/Y/Z/D"', '"/X/Y/Z/E"']
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt return anything!

Comment: This disregards curly braces.

Comment: @BA see edit. It returns `['"/X/Y/Z/C"', '"/X/Y/Z/D"', '"/X/Y/Z/E"']` when I call `parse()`

Comment: @AmyForbes. Thanks for the code but It really doesnt retun me anything. I just have black Terminal with no result. maybe it is my fault as I am new to learing and running programming. when I insert -- at the end, I get SyntaxError: invalid Syntax. I think you are using Canopy, I try to install it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the exact variations of your patters are, but you could use regex groups:

```
import re

myjunk = open("t.txt", "r")

for line in myjunk:
    if re.match('(/[A-Z])*', line)
        print line,
```

You may need to fiddle with the regex a bit, but the important point here is to invest a bit of time learning regex, and you won't have to deal with some of the unnecessarily complicated solutions suggested elsewhere. Regex is a mini language purpose built for so many things related to to text that it's really essential knowledge, even for the python newbie.  You'll be glad you put the time in!  And the python community is helpful, so why not join IRC and we'll see you in your favorite python channel for real time help.

Best of luck, let me know if you need more help.

PJ