# parsing logs - how to read part of line

Tags: python, parsing

I am trying to write something to parse and report a very specific part of a very large and detailed log file.

Essentially the structure could be described as:

```
Stuff I don't care about
Stuff I don't care about
Stuff I don't care about
More stuff I don't care about
DEBUG     2015-03-13 01:20:03  transfer.py:200  New transfer candidates: set([''])
Stuff I don't care about
Stuff I don't care about
Stuff I don't care about
More stuff I don't care about
DEBUG     2015-03-13 01:20:03  transfer.py:200  New transfer candidates: set(['foo/bar'])
Lots more stuff I don't care about
Even more stuff I don't care about
Still more stuff I don't care about
INFO      2015-03-13 09:00:01  transfer.py:363  Status info: {u'status': u'COMPLETE', u'name': u'bar', u'path': u'irrelevant content', u'directory': u'irrelevant content', u'microservice': u'Remove the processing directory', u'message': u'Fetched status for 67646105-2c08-47ec-93d1-b7d3f3b43d13 successfully.', u'type': u'SIP', u'uuid': u'67646105-2c08-47ec-93d1-b7d3f3b43d13'}
```

What I want to do is read through the file line by line, and find any instances of `New transfer candidates` where the contents of `set([''])` is not empty. In such instances, I want to grab the string (in this case `'foo/bar'`) and throw it in a variable. I also want to put the timestamp on that line in a variable.

As I continue reading line by line, I want to also be looking for lines that contain `Status info: {u'status': u'COMPLETE`"., and I then want to take the "name" (i.e. `u'name': u'bar'`) and put that in a variable (in this case `'bar'`). Same as above I want to put the timestamp in a variable.

The purpose here is to essentially see what time transfers are started, and when they are completed. I have some laughably basic crap written:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=
    "Python tool for generating performance statistics from Archivematica's "
    "Automation-tools log file")
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', type=file, help='log file to read')
args = parser.parse_args()
if not (args.input):
    parser.error('you did not specify a log file')

log = args.input
x = 0
for line in log:
    if 'New transfer candidates' in line:
        x = x+1
print x
```

My problem is that I'm not really sure how to approach finding these strings I'm looking for in these various parts of the lines?

Comment: The best approach would probably be to use [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) via the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re) module to match the sequence of characters you're interested in within the file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tips for reading in a complex file - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476946/tips-for-reading-in-a-complex-file-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module in the standard library or the open-source [`pyparsing`](https://pyparsing.wikispaces.com) module.

Following example shows how to use `re` to parse lines containing set data.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse
import re

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Python tool for generating performance statistics from Archivematica's Automation-tools log file")
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', type=file, help='log file to read')
args = parser.parse_args()

if not (args.input):
    parser.error('you did not specify a log file')

log = args.input

x = 0
regex1 = re.compile("New transfer candidates: set\(\['(.+)'\]\)")
for line in log:
    if 'New transfer candidates' in line:
        m = regex1.search(line)
        if m:
            print m.group(1)
        x = x+1
print x
```

Comment: Kudos for compiling your regex, but it's not actually necessary in python. They get cached.

Comment: Fantastic – I didn't know about the group method. Exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

```
import time
import re
import ast

with open('input.txt') as logfile:
    for line in logfile:
        line = line.strip()
        # search for level and timestamp
        match = re.match(r'(\S+)\s+(\S{10} \S{8})\s*(\S.*)$', line)
        if match:
            level = match.group(1)
            timestr = match.group(2)
            timestamp = time.mktime(time.strptime(timestr, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
            message = match.group(3)

            # transfer candidates
            match = re.match(r'.*New transfer candidates: set\((.*)\)', message)
            if match:
                candidates = ast.literal_eval(match.group(1))
                print 'New transfer candidate:', candidates
                continue

            # status info
            match = re.match(r'.*Status info: (.*)$', message)
            if match:
                info = ast.literal_eval(match.group(1))
                print 'Status info:', info
                continue

            print 'Unrecognized message.'
        else:
            print 'Unrecognized line.'
```