# Replace strings between two substrings by using python

Tags: python, string, str-replace

Here is my problem: there are ten different flags in a file,i need to replace the strings between the different flags.For example,the content of the file:

```
content of the file
...
...
...
FIRSTSTART
 111.467, 0.0, 0.0, 
    0.0, 0.0, 0.000, 0.000, 1.0, 3,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.960, 0.001, 1.0, 4,
FIRSTEND
SECONDSTART
 111.467, 0.0, 0.0, 
    0.0, 0.0, 0.000, 0.000, 1.0, 4,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.960, 0.001, 0.5, 4,
SECONDEND
THIRDSTART
 2.765, 0.0, 0.0,
   0.0, 0.0, 0.000, 0.000, 1.0, 2,
   0.0, 0.0, 1.470, 0.003, 4.0, 3,
THIRDEND
FORTHSTART
 2.765, 0.0, 0.0,
  0.0, 0.0, 0.000, 0.0000, 1.0, 1,
  0.0, 0.0, 2.350, 0.0040, 6.0, 3,
FORTHEND
FIFTHSTART
 2.765, 0.0, 0.0,
   0.0, 0.0, 0.000, 0.0000, 1.0, 3,
   0.0, 0.0, 2.410, 0.0040, 6.0, 3,
FIFTHEND
SIXTHSTART
 2.765, 0.0, 0.0,
   0.0, 0.0, 0.000, 0.0000, 1.0, 3,
   0.0, 0.0, 3.330, 0.0100, 12.0, 3,
SIXTHEND
SEVENTHSTART
 2.765, 0.0, 0.0,
  0.0, 0.0, 0.000, 0.0000,1.0, 3,
  0.0, 0.0, 3.960, 0.0100, 12.0, 3,
SEVENTHEND
EIGTHSTART
 40.00, 0.0, 0.0,
  0.0, 0.0, 0.000, 0.0000,1.0, 3,
  0.0, 0.0, 2.890, 0.0190, 1.717, 3,
EIGTHEND
NINETHSTART
 2.765, 0.0, 0.0,
   0.0, 0.0, 0.000, 0.0000, 1.0, 1,
   0.0, 0.0, 3.64, 0.0030, 0.5, 2,
NINETHEND
TENTHSTART
 2.765, 0.0, 0.0,
   0.0, 0.0, 0.000, 0.0000, 1.0, 1,
   0.0, 0.0, 4.39, 0.018, 10.0, 3,
TENTHEND 
...
...
...
content of the file...
...
```

I need replace the strings between the each "START" and "END" flags.Result I want is:

```
content of the file
    ...
    ...
    ...
    FIRSTSTART
    1a
    FIRSTEND
    SECONDSTART
    2b
    SECONDEND
    THIRDSTART
    3c
    THIRDEND
    FORTHSTART
    4d
    FORTHEND
    FIFTHSTART
    5e
    FIFTHEND
    SIXTHSTART
    6f
    SIXTHEND
    SEVENTHSTART
    7g
    SEVENTHEND
    EIGTHSTART
    8h
    EIGTHEND
    NINETHSTART
    9i
    NINETHEND
    TENTHSTART
    10j
    TENTHEND 
    ...
    ...
    ...
    content of the file...
    ...
```

So, how can i process this file.

Comment: Does the number of flags changes or is constant?

Comment: @Kadir the ten flags are constant.

Comment: You can use regex **sub** method for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tips for reading in a complex file - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476946/tips-for-reading-in-a-complex-file-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved like this in python: (data.txt is your content file)

```
import re

with open ("data.txt", "r") as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()

dict = {"FIRSTSTART(.+)FIRSTEND": "FIRSTSTART\n1a\nFIRSTEND", "SECONDSTART(.+)SECONDEND": "SECONDSTART\n2b\nSECONDEND",
        "THIRDSTART(.+)THIRDEND": "THIRDSTART\n3c\nTHIRDEND", "FORTHSTART(.+)FORTHEND": "FORTHSTART\n4d\nFORTHEND",
        "FIFTHSTART(.+)FIFTHEND": "FIFTHSTART\n5e\nFIFTHEND", "SIXTHSTART(.+)SIXTHEND": "SIXTHSTART\n6f\nSIXTHEND",
        "SEVENTHSTART(.+)SEVENTHEND": "SEVENTHSTART\n7g\nSEVENTHEND", "EIGTHSTART(.+)EIGTHEND": "EIGTHSTART\n8h\nEIGTHEND",
        "NINETHSTART(.+)NINETHEND": "NINETHSTART\n9i\nNINETHEND", "TENTHSTART(.+)TENTHEND": "TENTHSTART\n10j\nTENTHEND"
        }

for key, value in dict.iteritems():
    re_comp = re.compile(key, re.DOTALL)
    data = re_comp.sub(value, data)

print data
```